# What are the device files for the serial ports device drivers in OS X?

Tags: linux, osx

In Linux, the following are the device files for the serial ports drivers:

```
/dev/ttyS0
/dev/ttyS1
/dev/ttyS2
/dev/ttyS3
```

I have found the following files in OS X (El Capitan):

[image]

Are those files the device files for the serial ports drivers in OS X?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632586/macos-whats-the-difference-between-dev-tty-and-dev-cu

Answer (score 0):

Open Apple menu, click "About This Mac", "System Report..."; you will find serial ports in the categories on the left; probably as a device under "USB".

I hadn't seen a Mac with a hardwired serial port for a long time; for the "virtual" ones - eg USB-Serial adapters - the names are somewhat... descriptive.  They can be eg "/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port".